# Checking if a variable double type less 0

Tags: c#

If I have a variable double type, how should I check if the variable less then 0?
I guess, if I just write

```
if (value < 0) { //... }
```

that's not right, is it?

Comment: that would work, but if your picky; `0.0`

Comment: When you have a question like this, why not just try to compile and see what happens?

Comment: The compiler won't tell you if its the right way to do this, at a guess, OP is a new programmer making sure what he is doing is correct

Comment: @Sayse thanks a lot! I'm really newbee.

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi I KNOW it works but I want to know the right way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It is* right. Don't see ay problem with this.

The sign of a double is not a subject of precision calculations or anything else. So the number or *positive*, or *negative*. There is no other option.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, its correct. cause VS itself can convert (int) 0 to (double).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler in Visual Studio is 'clever' enough to implicitly convert the `int` value to a `double` type. It is done during the lexical analysis of the code. In some other languages (I think that ANSI C is the example here) your code would fail, but Visual Studio is a well-developed environment ;)